# how to find an element value in xml when we have multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I want to get the value of the element *rsm:CIIHExchangedDocument/ram:ID*
But I have problem with multiple namespaces, and null values (I can not know if requested element exists)

It can be achieved this way:

```
XElement invoice = XElement.Load(invoiceStream);
XNamespace rsm = invoice.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("rsm");
XNamespace ram = invoice.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ram");
if ((invoice.Element(rsm + "CIIHExchangedDocument")) != null)
{
    if (invoice.Element(rsm + "CIIHExchangedDocument").Element(ram + "ID") != null)
    {
        string id = invoice.Element(rsm + "CIIHExchangedDocument").Element(ram + "ID").Value;
    }
}
```

but I think using xPath will suit my needs better. I want to do something like this:

```
invoice.XPathSelectElement("rsm:CIIHExchangedDocument/ram:ID"):
```

I need to retrieve a lot of elements of different depth in the document, and I have many namespaces.

What is the simplest whay to achive this? Execution speed is also important to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the XPathNavigator class.  An example of how to use can be found here [XpathNaivigator](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333)